# Placing views inside a UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, gridview, uiview

This is what I want to achieve.

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
|                     view 1 here                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                       view 2 here                    |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                    view 3 here                       |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
|                                                      |
| -----------------------------------------------------|
```

I want to have a scrollview with 3 views in it. I am doing the following.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    keeperView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    aanvallerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    middenvelderView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    listView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280,2360);
    [listView addSubview:keeperView];
    [listView addSubview:aanvallerView];
    [listView addSubview:middenvelderView];
}
```

But it only shows one view. Does anybody knows what the problem is?

Kind regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your viewDidLoadMethod:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1100)];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 300)];
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[scrollView addSubview:view1];

UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 320, 300)];
[view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[scrollView addSubview:view2];

UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 750, 320, 300)];
[view3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[scrollView addSubview:view3];
```

Result:

[image: Different View]

[image: Different views 2]

[image: Different Views 3]

All 3 Views are on the Scrollview! :)

By using addSubview, you can now put all the things you wish on the views ;)
You could even make another scrollview with a scrollview ^^

Answer (score 4):

It could be that they don't have a frame. Call `initWithFrame`: on the `UIViews`